# Prove why the given function is discontinuous at the given value of $a$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x+1 & \quad  if \space x \leq 0 \\
            x-2 & \quad if\space x > 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

When $a=0$

My professor is trying to encourage us to do these proofs from definitions of continuity and then conversely discontinuity

So we have the Sequential Criterion of Continuity (SCC)

$\textit {Let f be a function and a be a number in the interior of the domain of f. Then the following are equivalent:}$
$(i)\textit{ f is continuous at a;}$

$(ii)\space \textit {If s is a sequence in the domain of f such that $lim_n S_n = a,$ then $lim_n f(s_n) = f(a)$}$

I also have a Corollary to this theorem that says

$ \textit {Let f be a function with the number a in the interior of its domain.$\\$ If there exists two sequences s and t both converging to a such that$\\$ $lim_n f(s_n) \ne lim_n f(t_n)$, then f is discontinuous at a.}$

So based on these two facts what is my best approach to proving this is discontinuous, or while I have to use some form of the limit definition to prove its discontinuous.

I have tried to start but I am just not sure how to begin proving this using the definitions I have thus far for continuity.

I appreciate all recommendations, solution formats, etc. and if you would be willing to tell me what is the easiest generalized form for proving discontinuity.

Comment: Find a sequence $s_n$ that converges to $0$ from the right and show $f(s_n)$ converges to something different from $f(0)$.

Comment: anything more you can give me? am I doing a generic sequence $s_n$ or am I actually hand picking a sequence?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$. But $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}-2 \neq  1$. And for the Corollary: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}-2 = -2 \neq 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} -\frac{1}{n}+1$

Comment: @Bry You can use $s_n=1/n$, as suggested by Weaam.  Or you can argue generically that as long as $s_n\rightarrow 0$ *and* $s_n>0$ $\forall$ $n$ then $f(s_n)\rightarrow -2$ while $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Okay so s$s_n = \frac {1}{n}$ and the $lim_n s_n = 0$ which is my a, so thats the first half of (ii) and then $lim_n f(s_n$) which is -2 $\ne f(a)$ which is 1? Is that the logic?

Comment: @GregoryGrant thank You for the clear explanation i appreciate it

Comment: @Bry No problem

Comment: Okay real quick for something like 
$f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x^2 & \quad  if \space x \leq 1 \\
            x+1 & \quad if\space x > 1
        \end{array}
    \right.$
Where a=1

then let $s_n = \frac {1}{n} +1$ so $lim_n s_n= 1$ then $lim_n f(s_n)=2$ cause $f(s_n)= ( \frac {1}{n} +1) +1 $ which does not equal $f(a) = 1$

Comment: that shows its discontinuous by SCC?